# Transfer protocol for sending user uploaded files to a remote server?

Tags: security, ftp, upload, sftp, ftps

I'm used to working with user-uploaded files to the same server, and transferring my own files to a remote server. But not transferring user-uploaded files to a remote server.

I'm looking for the best (industry) practice for selecting a transfer protocol in this regard.

My application is running Django on a Linux Server and the files live on a Windows Server.

Does it not matter which protocol I choose as long as it's secure (FTPS, SFTP, HTTPS)? Or is one better than the other in terms of performance/security **specifically in regards to user-uploaded files?**

Please do not link to questions that explain the differences of protocols, I am asking specifically in the context of user-uploaded files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you choose a standard protocol that provides (mutual) authentication, encryption and message authentication, there is not much difference security-wise. If all of this is provided by a layer of TLS in your chosen protocol (like in all of your examples), you can't make a big mistake on a design level (but implementation is key, many security bugs are bugs of implementation, and not design flaws). Such protocols might differ in the supported list of algorithms for different purposes though.

Performance-wise there can be quite significant differences, it depends on what you want to optimize for. If you choose HTTPS, you won't be able to keep a connection open for a long time, and would most probably have to bear the overhead of the whole connection setup with authentication and everything, for every transmitted file. (Well, you can actually keep a https connection open, but that would be quite a custom implementation for such file uploads.) Choosing FTPS/SFTP you will be able to keep a connection open and transmit as many files as you want, but would probably have to have more complex error handling logic (sometimes connections terminate without the underlying sockets knowing about it for a while and so on). So in short I think HTTPS would be more resilient, but secure FTP would be more performant for many small files.

It's also an architecture question, by using HTTPS, you would be able to implement all of this in your application code, while something like FTP would mean dependence on external components, which might be important from an operational point of view (think about how this will actually be deployed and whether there is already a devops function to manage proper operations).

Ultimately it's just a design decision you have to make, the above is just a few things that came to mind without knowing all the circumstances, and not at all a comprehensive list of things to consider.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer